# Interaction effect in a multiple regression vs split sample

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, interaction

Until now I thought I understand an interaction effect. I interpreted it always as the change of slope conditional on some dummy=1. Perhaps I am wrong.

I have a model and add an interaction dummy D, ($D=1$ for European countries, $0$ for rest).

$y=\alpha + D\beta_1 +x\beta_2 + xD\beta_3 +\nu $

I ran the regression using just the observations where $D=1$:

if $D=1$ *regress* $y=\alpha + x\gamma +\xi $

Unsurprisingly, I find that $\gamma=\beta_2+\beta_3=-0.25$

The confusion comes however with a multivariate regression with more than one covariate.

My model is now:

$y=\alpha + D\beta_1 +x\beta_2 + xD\beta_3 + \Omega\delta +\nu $

with $\Omega$ being a vector of covariates.

Now when I rerun my model only with the observations where $D=1$.

if $D=1$ *regress* $y=\alpha + x\gamma + \Omega\delta +\xi $

I find to my big surprise that $\gamma \ne \beta_2+\beta_3$

In fact, $\gamma=-0.6$ and highly significant while $\beta_2+\beta_3=0.4$ and insignificant.

What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have to realize it that a split sample is different from a interaction effect.

Interaction effect with x concerns only a change of the slope *of that particular independent variable x*, leaving all other slopes constant.

Splitting the sample is equivalent to having an interaction dummy *for every independent variable*. In other words, you allow to to have a change in the slope for every independent variable.

So essentially,

$y=\alpha + D+ \beta_1 D x_1+ \beta_2D x_2+...+\beta_n Dx_n +\varepsilon \equiv  if D=1: y=(\alpha + D)+\beta_1x_1+  \beta_2x_2+...+\beta_nx_n + \varepsilon $

If use use just one interaction dummy on one regressand, you use different assumptions that result in a totally different model.